# How to exclude <a> tags url to regex?

Tags: php, regex, web

The current code is excluding the test link but not the `test` url.

Please see my current code here:

```
var regexp = new RegExp( "\\b(" +  data.title + ")\\b(?![^<a]*>|[^<>]*</a>)"  , 'i');
```

This regex is used by searching words from the content: test

Example Output: `This is a test page.` The word 'test' will be highlighted and will be linked somewhere base on my dictionary.

Issue: If the content have this HTML  tag. The URL with the word test will be highlighted as well and result to broken tags. URL should be excluded to regex.

Example: This is a `<a href="https://sample.com/to-test/">test</a>`

`Please see the link of regex:` https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/3

Comment: could you provide a text, your current output , and your desired output,

Comment: @ha-neul edited

Comment: @winresh24, not sure what you want correct in your current regex. Here, https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/2, it does not seem to match the url, so not sure what the issue is

Comment: @Prasanna hi the issue is I want to exclude the URL from the regex I currently have. My regex purposes are to search for some words from the content. So when there is a URL in the content which matches the search word it broke the tags. And the URL shouldn't be included in the first place.

Comment: @Prasanna Please see this: https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/3

Comment: @winresh24, now I get it. One simpler solution is you can use this pattern, https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/3, to match `<a>..</a>` or other content. If you only try to consume group1 you will get the text outside the `<a>` tag. Not sure if that is sufficient for your use case

Comment: @Prasanna can you hand me a sample? and probably make it an answer to this question so I can mark it as answered? Can you please add as well to exclude a specific word.

Answer (score 0):

One option to exclude the text in `<a>` tag is https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/4

**Pattern:** `<a.*?</a>|\b(estoppel)\b`

**Explanation:**

- First try to match any content within `<a>..</a>` tag.
- If the first pattern failed then match with the alternate, `\b(estoppel)\b`. This way Group 1 will be available only if the second part of the pattern matches. We can only work on the values captured in Group1.

Comment: One more thing. How can I exclude a word?

Comment: @winresh24, not sure if I get it. What word do you want to be excluded? Can you give a sample string and what the output you expect?

Comment: A specific word let say `default`' in a senctence `This is a default word`

Comment: @winresh24, assuming you need to exclude a line if it contains `default`. Based on the same logic, https://regex101.com/r/aamuTy/5 should work.